# Access 2013 AuditTrail table showing GUID as chinese symbols

Tags: vba, ms-access, guid

I have an audit trail table setup with an MS Access form that works although the *ID* (PK) is a `GUID` and when the data shows in my *AuditTrail* table it shows as Chinese characters. I can't work out why its not showing the actual ID.

In my *BeforeUpdate* event I have the following code which helps but not 100%:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Call AuditChanges("ID", "NEW")
    Else
        Call AuditChanges("ID", "EDIT")
    End If
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & " in " & _
          VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule, vbOKOnly, "Error" 

End Sub 

'I am using this code to for the AuditChanges
Sub AuditChanges (IDField As String, UserAction As String)
    On Error GoTo AuditChanges_Err
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim datTimeCheck As Date
    Dim strUserID As String

    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAuditTrail", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    datTimeCheck = Now()
    strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")

    Select Case useraction

        Case "EDIT"
        For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If ctl.Tag = "Audit" Then
                If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                        ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                        ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                        ![OldValue] = ctl.OldValue
                        ![NewValue] = ctl.Value
                        ![UserID] = strUserID
                        ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
            End If
            Next ctl

        Case Else
            With rst
                .AddNew
                ![DateTime] = datTimeCheck
                ![UserID] = strUserID
                ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                ![Action] = useraction
                ![RecordID] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                .Update
            End With
    End Select

AuditChanges_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

AuditChanges_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR!"
    Resume AuditChanges_Exit
End Sub
```

Although the *ID* is not showing correctly. I tried using `StringFromGUID` but this throws an error of cannot find the field. Example of GUID is `{EF95C08E-D344-42B3-B678-2A64A50366DE}`.

I hope someone can help although this is probably the wrong way of doing this it is the only way I have managed so far. Thanks.

Comment: Please screenshot to show *Chinese characters*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Application.StringFromGUID` takes a byte array, and you've stored the bytes of your GUID as a string.

Access uses UTF-16 to store strings. Because a large fraction of two-byte UTF-16 characters are Chinese, you often get Chinese characters if you display random bytes as a string.

The following code casts them back to a bytearray, and then calls `StringFromGUID`. I've tested it on Access 2016 with default locale settings.

```
Public Function StringFromStringGUID(strGUIDBytes As String) As String
    If Len(strGUIDBytes) = 8 Then
        Dim bytes() As Byte
        bytes = strGUIDBytes
        StringFromStringGUID = Application.StringFromGUID(bytes)
    Else
        'Invalid string, GUID = 16 bytes, Access stores UTF-16 strings = 2 bytes per character
    End If
End Function
```

You can use this in queries/VBA to cast those strings back to GUIDs

Comment: Thanks for this but I am not sure how to use this? I have added this as a module but I am not sure if I should be calling this function in my BeforeUpdate event or in my other AuditChanges module? sorry I really don't know how to get this to work.

Comment: @New2Programming You can use this to decode your existing entries in queries and VBA. For example, `SELECT StringFromStringGUID(OldValue), StringFromStringGUID(NewValue) FROM tblAuditTrail WHERE FieldName = "SomeGUIDField"`. You can also use this in `UPDATE` queries to fix the incorrectly stored GUIDs. For future entries, I recommend you check if the field is a GUID field, and there you'll likely still be able to just use `Application.StringFromGUID` before storing it.

Comment: Thanks this works its just a shame I couldn't put it straight in my original code as I didn't want to have to use an update query but since doing so it works perfectly.